# Where did my purchased Apps go when I upgraded my Phone?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s

I have read through many questions here and totally understand that when you upgrade your phone your purchased apps should be accessible for reinstalling at https://play.google.com/store.

I upgraded my phone yesterday from a Galaxy SII to a Galaxy S3 and I was given a guarantee in the shop that all the apps I purchased would be available when I log into to GooglePlay.  The fact that they are not there is the reason for this question.  I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and was using the same Google Play account to manage my apps.

Im guessing that because my Android platform v4+ and my old phone was v2.2 that some of my apps may not be compatible but I wasnt expecting not to be able to see them (after all they are apps I purchased).  Any help would be much appreciated, because the apps for my Galaxy Tab are not available either.  My login details for Google has been the same through out.

Comment: Can you try to log-in at the Google Play website, and see if your apps are still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this answer doesn't get to the root cause or the "why it happened" but the issue is now resolved. It may help others if their purchased applications are suddenly not available on Google Play for installation on a new device.

I received an notification to update my Android Firmware and reboot. I followed the instructions, went into Google Play and my purchased items were now available.  I can't explain why, they just were.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the same Google login - then you should be able to find them under My Apps in Google Play and they should be marked as Purchased. (On your phone - on the web you'll find them under My Android Apps).

You can also click on Orders and Devices at the bottom of the page - if they don't show up in that list. (And next to each you have "Report A Problem")

And worst case scenario, if these apps are paid for, you should at least be able to find them in your Google Checkout history - and contact Google to refresh your account.  HTH.

Answer (score 1):

In the new Market application you need to slide the tab sideways when viewing the Installed applications to view All applications, you might have missed that at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the [google play](https://play.google.com) web site, there is a list of all the apps that you have ever installed on your device, including purchased ones.